# Combinatorics Counting Problem (Team Selection)

Tags: combinatorics

A hockey team is made up of 5 players each from Scotland, Wales, and Ireland, and 3 from England. In how many ways can the team of 11 players be selected such that there are more English players than Irish players?

This is a real-life problem I was trying to figure out, and my attempt was to count through every possible selection where there are more English players than Irish players - e.g 3E,1I/3E,2I/2E,1I/3E,0I/2E,0I/1E,0I, however, this is a very tedious process and I was wondering what the best solution to this problem is. All help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have only six cases to deal with and you think it is a very tedious process?

Comment: @Batominovski No, I was just wondering if there was an easier method...

Comment: Maybe there is, but if the easier way to count is more difficult to think of, I am not sure if it will qualify as an "easier way."  What you attempted or what quasi wrote seems to be the most natural way to tackle the problem, and it is not even a difficult or messy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of pairs $(e,i)$, where $e,i$ are integers with $1\le e \le 3$ and $0 \le i < e$.

Explicitly we have $S=\{(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)\}$.

For $(e,i)\in S$, the number of ways to form a team with $e$ English players and $i$ Irish players is
$$\binom{3}{e}\binom{5}{i}\binom{10}{11-(e+i)}$$
hence the number of teams satisfying the specified condition is 
$$
{\large{\sum_{(e,i)\in S}}}\binom{3}{e}\binom{5}{i}\binom{10}{11-(e+i)}
=
3+30+675+45+600+2100
=
3453
$$

Comment: Isn't there a problem say with 10 choose 8, as there is a restriction that there are only 5 Scottish players and 5 Welsh players... isn't this something that needs to be factored in? Anyhow, thank you very much!

Comment: We are just choosing $8$ from the remaining $10$, regarded as a $10$-element set.

Comment: But you can't, for example, choose 8 Welsh people as that is not possible as there are only 5 maximum Welsh people. Does this not need to be taken into account?

Comment: In the count, we are regarding the players from Scotland and Wales as a single group of $10$ players. In other words, $10$ distinct people, without regard to whether they are Scottish or Welsh.